# ¿Como volver hacia atras en un grafo? - C#

Tags: c#

cree la siguente estructura

```
  public class nodo
    {


        public string info = null;
        public nodo[] nodl = new nodo[2] ;



    }

nodo nod0=new nodo();
        nod0.info = "1";
        nodo nod1 = new nodo();
        nod1.info="2";
        nod0.nodl[0]=nod1;
        nodo nod2 = new nodo();
        nod2.info="3";
        nod0.nodl[1]=nod2;
```

graficamente deberia tener esta forma

```
           _nod0_
          !      ! 
          !      !
         nod1  nod2
```

Mi pregunta es puedo con esta estructura pararme en nod0.nodl[0] y ir a fijarme con algun recorrido la info de nod0 y de nod2, es decir subir hasta nod0 y de ahi ir a hasta no hasta nod2, por que estuve probrando hacer arboles binarios con mas ramas y puedo recorrerlos con recursion el problema es que siempre tengo que pararme en la raiz , ¿pero si quisiera recorrerlo desde otro punto necesitaria otro tipo de estructura?

Answer (score 0):

Comentas que has podido recorrer un arbol (que es básicamente lo que estás haciendo) pero al recorrer la parte de la izq se te paraba en la raiz?

Para recorrer árboles en su totalidad tienes 3 métodos que puedes utilizar según 
 el orden que te interese.

Los recorridos son:

- Recorrido en preorden
- Recorrido en inorden
- Recorrido en postorden

Con estos 3 recorridos pasas por todos los nodos del arbol como he dicho, en el orden que tu decidas.

Te paso el enlace de Wikipedia para que veas como realizar cada recorrido: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recorrido_de_%C3%A1rboles

Comment: El tema es asi cree el algoritmo de preorden y despues cree un postorden falso... podriamos decir... por que tome el resultado de preorden y solo lo inverti, lo cual viene siendo un post orden ... pero con la estructura que cree no se como estando parado en nod0.nodl[0] como origen ir hacia arriba , es mas no lo veamos como nod0.nodl[0] veamos como nod1 imaginemos q estamos en nod1 ¿como voy a nod0?

Comment: Segun vengo pensando la estructura que cree solo me permite aplicar preorden puesto que solo puedo empezar desde la raiz obligatoriamente...pero se me ocurre plantear los datos como una matriz en lugar como  una clase y quizas asi pueda ir de atras para adelante... pero es un planteo ... no lo tengo muy claro todavia...